# Changes made to REST server using APIs not reflected in Composer Playground?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I have defined a Business Network, installed and deployed it on my local machine. I have also create a local `REST` server for testing. When I am submitting transactions through API calls, they are reflected in the `REST` server (which I can verify through `GET` requests on the same APIs) but not being reflected in the Composer Playground 'All Transactions'. Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

`Composer-playground` only provide easy access to the hyperledger network.

So, if you made the transaction `REST-API`, than you can see the same transaction in local `playground` also and vice-versa.

So, check that you connected to same `business-network` in playgroud.

Run `composer-playground` command, connect to network installed, that's it.

Comment: Issue was with card importing. Solved it. Thank you anyway!